# How to set proper resolution at bootloader and screen login

Tags: grub2, 20.04, display, display-resolution, login-screen

I'm having trouble with screen resolution on Ubuntu 20.04 with an HP 2009v monitor, which has native resolution 1600x900 pixels.

Problem is that when I startup the computer (with integrated Intel graphics), monitor says that received resolution is out of range, displaying nothing. With some troubles, I managed to set right resolution in user session with xrandr commands. Now I'd like to set proper resolution at least at login screen, then possibly to the grub bootloader too.

I edited the /etc/gdm3/Init/Default file adding following lines, but nothing changed:

```
xrandr --newmode "1600x900_60.00"  118.25  1600 1696 1856 2112  900 903 908 934 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-3 1600x900_60.00
xrandr --output HDMI-3 --mode 1600x900_60.00
```

I also copied ~/.config/monitors.xml to /var/lib/.config and nothing changed too

How could I set proper display resolution at login screen?

Furthermore, I'd need to set proper resolution at grub and during ubuntu startup. I edited /etc/default/grub adding the lines

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=1600x900
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD=1600x900
```

but nothing changed here too. Display keep saying that input is out of range.

How can I troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: I suspect (don't ask me why) that this issue has something to do with framebuffer resolution. If I enter the command "cat /sys/class/graphics/fb0/modes" the output is just: U:1920x1080p-0. Which is actually wrong. Is there a way to tell my computer that those resolution is not supported by my display?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, after more than a month of researching and editing a bunch of config files, the real source of the problem was a cheap HDMI to VGA adapter I bought on aliexpress. Switching to a more expensive one bought on Amazon solved the problem. Resolution is correctly set without any particular setting. I can't explain why this brand new (even though cheap) adapter can't transmit correctly EDID data from video card to VGA monitor... Unbelievable!

Answer (score 2):

As to the login screen: try a static X11 configuration by creating a file /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-monitor.conf with content such as

```
Section "Device"
  Identifier "Configured Video Device"
  Driver "intel"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
  Identifier  "Configured Monitor"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
  Identifier "Configured Screen"
  Device "Configured Video Device"
  Monitor "Configured Monitor"
  SubSection "Display"
    Modes "1600x900" "640x480"
  EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Useful web page: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution

As to the grub screen: did you consult the grub info file?

**Note on gdm3**

This only works with gdm3 if wayland is disabled in /etc/gdm3/custom.conf, i.e. remove in /etc/gdm3/custom.conf the '#' comment sign from the line

```
#WaylandEnable=false
```

Comment: Should that filepath be `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/`?

Comment: Given the choice, system-wide configuration changes should be done under /etc, where they are less likely to be overwritten on upgrades. In my tests, the configuration file under /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/ was picked up.

Comment: My ubuntu does not have it.  Did you create that directory yourself `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/`?

Comment: I do not remember now whether it was there or whether I created it.

Comment: @Siep, wouldn't I need to edit a gdm3 config file rather than an X one? /etc/X11 is empty. Should I create the directory xorg.conf.d and create the config file as you suggested? I'm suspecting that this won't change anything, but I will give it a try.

Comment: Regarding grub: what is a grub info file? Do you mean grub configuration file (/etc/default/grub)? As I described in my question, I edited it, without success.

Comment: Grub info file: type 'info grub' in a terminal window. On 20.04, this info file is part of grub2-common. As to adding xorg.conf.d, I should not hesitate to do that. As to editing a gdm config file: some display managers allow configuring the display, some do not. My own experience is with xdm, which allows it, and with lxdm, which does not.

Comment: I tried to add a manually edited xorg.conf into /etc/X11 (even if I'm not that sure I wrote it correctly) but nothing has changed. In the meanwhile I've discovered that the EDID data provided by my monitor is incorrect and I don't know how to override it. I also wrote a 10-monitor.conf into /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d as suggested but again, nothing happened. I'm really lost. I can't enumerate how many man pages, forum, ask and so on I've read in the past month :(